# How to extract single plots from facet_plot and maintain scaling?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

From one dataframe of data in long format, the first plot call below gives me this matrix of joyplots: [image] There is one ridgeline and color scale across each of the 13 scenarios.

However, when I try to show just one plot per page, in the looped 'SingleScenario' plot call below, the scaling is done for the individual subset of data per scenario min and max (each plot has the full yellow to purple color scale, and I'm not sure if the ridgeheight scale is preserved or reset).

How do I plot individual scenarios as single pages and keep the original scaling?  This way, differences will be visualized by paging down through a 13-page pdf.

Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(viridis)

matrix <- ggplot(df, aes(watermonth, as.integer(wateryear), height = inflow, group=as.integer(wateryear)
           , fill=cumWYinf))  + geom_ridgeline(stat = "identity",
          show.legend = F, scale = 0.005, alpha = 0.8) + facet_wrap(~scenario, nr=4, nc=4) +
          scale_fill_viridis() 


scenarios <- c("q0", "e1", "e2", "e3", "e4", "e5", "cwc30", "l1", "l2", "l3", "l4", "l5", "cwc70")

for(i in 1:length(scenarios)) {

facets <- c(paste0(scenarios[i]))

SingleScenario <- ggplot(df[df$scenario %in% facets,], aes(watermonth, as.integer(wateryear),
      height = inflow, group=as.integer(wateryear), fill = cumWYinf)) +
      geom_ridgeline(stat = "identity", show.legend = F, scale = 0.005, alpha = 0.9) +
      + facet_wrap(~scenario, nr=1, nc=1) + scale_fill_viridis() 

SingleScenario
ggsave(paste(scenarios[i],".pdf"), dpi = 300, width = 17, height = 11, units = "in") }
```

Thank you.

```
 date        watermonth wateryear inflow scenario SacWYT SJRWYT cumWYinf
  <date>           <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>    <chr>  <int>  <int>    <dbl>
1 1921-10-31          1      1922  66.38       q0      2      2  2293.78
2 1921-11-30          2      1922  50.65       q0      2      2  2293.78
3 1921-12-31          3      1922  82.09       q0      2      2  2293.78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to answer without having example dataset to test my prediction, but can you try adjusting fill with `limits = ...`:

`scale_fill_viridis(limits = range(df$cumWYinf))`

This way all plots will have the same scale.

Comment: Thank you @PoGibas!  That took care of the color fill perfectly.  I'm curious if the height scale needs something similar, to see the full height range?

Comment: @doconnor yes, I would do similar thing for the `y-axis`! You can do that simply with: `scale_y_continous(limits = range(df$yourYvariable))`. If my answer solved your problem you can accept it :-)

Comment: @doconnor can you accept my answer so we can close this question. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you again. It solved the color scale but I'm still working on the y-scale heights. When I add scale_y_continuous(limits = range(df$inflow), the plot goes blank, and I think it is altering the overarching y-axis of the joy groups (each row is a year, 1922-2003) instead of the y-axis per row (the monthly inflow, ranging from near zero to ~1500).

Comment: @doconnor I can fix that, but you need to post you data somewhere

Comment: Great. I really appreciate it.  I just added the first few rows above - there are 13 scenarios, each of which has monthly inflow in 984 rows, from 10/'31 to 9/'03 (scenarios: q0, 1e, 2e, 3e, etc).

Comment: I can share a gist of the data in .csv format if it would help.

Comment: Here's the data https://gist.github.com/dbo-usbr/2bb3f83b190b67e541ae599b86f85050 thank you.

Comment: I think I simply had the y limits incorrectly not within the ggplot call and after the plot call. I think having it inside of ggplot does the trick:          
 ..cumWYinf, scale_y_continuous(limits = range(df$inflow)))) + geom... + facet_wrap.. + scale_fill  ..?

Comment: Yes! Might be the case. I just started looking into ggridges as ggjoy has been deprecated

Comment: Great. I'll consider case closed unless one of us or someone else finds otherwise.